# Spring Integration Java DSL + Activiti

Tags: spring-integration, activiti, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I watched video about Spring + Activiti https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0PV_8Lew3vg.
I need to make the process moved immediately to the `serviceTask` where Activiti invokes my gateway, sending a request message to queue (rabbitMQ). After the request message is sent, the process stops. Then `serviceTask` starts up again as soon as response message is in the response queue.
The `serviceTask` may take a very long time.

I tried the example from webinar and it is working fine but sync.

This is my ActivitiDemoApplication.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine;
import org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.activiti.engine.TaskService;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.delegate.ActivityExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.runtime.ProcessInstance;
import org.activiti.spring.integration.ActivitiInboundGateway;
import org.activiti.spring.integration.IntegrationActivityBehavior;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.integration.activiti.gateway.AsyncActivityBehaviorMessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.support.GenericHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
// @EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class ActivitiDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ActivitiDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationActivityBehavior activitiDelegate(
            ActivitiInboundGateway activitiInboundGateway) {
        return new IntegrationActivityBehavior(activitiInboundGateway);
    }

    @Bean
    ActivitiInboundGateway inboundGateway(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
        return new ActivitiInboundGateway(processEngine, "processed");
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow inboundProcess(
            ActivitiInboundGateway activitiInboundGateway,
            PhotoService photoService) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(activitiInboundGateway)
                .handle(new GenericHandler<ActivityExecution>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object handle(ActivityExecution execution,
                            Map<String, Object> headers) {
                        try {
                            photoService.Execute();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(execution)
                                .setHeader("processed", (Object) true)
                                .copyHeaders(headers).build();
                    }
                }).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource database() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=activiti")
                .username("activiti")
                .password("activiti")
                .driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
                .build();
    }

    @RestController
    public static class MyRestController {
        @Autowired
        private RuntimeService runtimeService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/start-my-process", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public void startMyProcess() {
            ProcessInstance p = runtimeService
                    .startProcessInstanceByKey("TestProcess");
            System.out.println("id: " + p.getId());
            System.out.println("count: "
                    + runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().count());
        }

    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
class PhotoService {
    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    public void Execute() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("debug 1");
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("debug 2");
    }
}
```

this is my TestProcess.bmpn20.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
    xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"
    typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath"
    targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef" xmlns:modeler="http://activiti.com/modeler"
    modeler:version="1.0ev" modeler:exportDateTime="20151228174550"
    modeler:modelId="969411" modeler:modelVersion="1"
    modeler:modelLastUpdated="1451324745996">
    <process id="TestProcess" name="TestProcess" isExecutable="true">
        <startEvent id="startEvent1" />
        <intermediateCatchEvent id="sid-0BAE26E1-BB48-49FD-91E4-246B85C6B8B1">
            <timerEventDefinition>
                <timeDuration>PT20S</timeDuration>
            </timerEventDefinition>
        </intermediateCatchEvent>
        <endEvent id="sid-23D49CE8-B018-4ABF-871F-07F42508C98A" />
        <sequenceFlow id="sid-53B3780A-A1F6-4059-9660-D56CECD236F1"
            sourceRef="sid-0BAE26E1-BB48-49FD-91E4-246B85C6B8B1" targetRef="sid-23D49CE8-B018-4ABF-871F-07F42508C98A" />
        <serviceTask id="task-integration" name="task integration"
            activiti:delegateExpression="#{activitiDelegate}" />
        <sequenceFlow id="sid-4DDAAA87-536F-4E69-BDC8-09B96DB7BD07"
            sourceRef="task-integration" targetRef="sid-0BAE26E1-BB48-49FD-91E4-246B85C6B8B1" />
        <sequenceFlow id="sid-3F3E9366-BAF9-40AF-9E34-E324A91291F7"
            sourceRef="startEvent1" targetRef="task-integration" />
    </process>
    <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_TestProcess">
        <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="TestProcess" id="BPMNPlane_TestProcess">
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startEvent1"
                id="BPMNShape_startEvent1">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="100.0" y="163.0" />
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-0BAE26E1-BB48-49FD-91E4-246B85C6B8B1"
                id="BPMNShape_sid-0BAE26E1-BB48-49FD-91E4-246B85C6B8B1">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="31.0" width="31.0" x="480.0" y="162.5" />
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="sid-23D49CE8-B018-4ABF-871F-07F42508C98A"
                id="BPMNShape_sid-23D49CE8-B018-4ABF-871F-07F42508C98A">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="28.0" width="28.0" x="570.0" y="161.0" />
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="task-integration"
                id="BPMNShape_task-integration">
                <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="340.0" y="135.0" />
            </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-3F3E9366-BAF9-40AF-9E34-E324A91291F7"
                id="BPMNEdge_sid-3F3E9366-BAF9-40AF-9E34-E324A91291F7">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="130.0" y="178.0" />
                <omgdi:waypoint x="162.5" y="178.0" />
                <omgdi:waypoint x="157.0" y="178.0" />
                <omgdi:waypoint x="340.0" y="161.521327014218" />
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-4DDAAA87-536F-4E69-BDC8-09B96DB7BD07"
                id="BPMNEdge_sid-4DDAAA87-536F-4E69-BDC8-09B96DB7BD07">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="440.0" y="176.4218009478673" />
                <omgdi:waypoint x="480.0062629076814" y="177.5594197983227" />
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
            <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-53B3780A-A1F6-4059-9660-D56CECD236F1"
                id="BPMNEdge_sid-53B3780A-A1F6-4059-9660-D56CECD236F1">
                <omgdi:waypoint x="512.0" y="178.5" />
                <omgdi:waypoint x="540.5" y="178.5" />
                <omgdi:waypoint x="540.5" y="175.0" />
                <omgdi:waypoint x="570.0" y="175.0" />
            </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
        </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
    </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

I would like to make async process.

```
<serviceTask id="task-integration" name="task integration" activiti:delegateExpression="#{activitiDelegate}"/>
```

When Activiti invokes my gateway "#{activitiDelegate}", i want to move a request message to a RequestQueue for execution "photoService.Execute()". Then process starts up again when response message is received from ResponseQueue.

```
return MessageBuilder.withPayload(execution).setHeader("processed", (Object) true).copyHeaders(headers).build();
```

I do not know how can i implement amqp with gateway

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationActivityBehavior activitiDelegate(
            ActivitiInboundGateway activitiInboundGateway) {
        return new IntegrationActivityBehavior(activitiInboundGateway);
    }

    @Bean
    ActivitiInboundGateway inboundGateway(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
        return new ActivitiInboundGateway(processEngine, "processed");
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow inboundProcess(
            ActivitiInboundGateway activitiInboundGateway,
            PhotoService photoService) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(activitiInboundGateway)
                .handle(new GenericHandler<ActivityExecution>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object handle(ActivityExecution execution,
                            Map<String, Object> headers) {
                        try {
                            photoService.Execute();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(execution)
                                .setHeader("processed", (Object) true)
                                .copyHeaders(headers).build();
                    }
                }).get();
    }
```

I am sorry, but i am begginer in java spring integration. I hope that my explain is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your question isn't clear, especially for those who isn't familiar with one of the mentioned Frameworks.

You say `serviceTask`, but don't show it in the code. I only can guess that you talk about that `photoService`, which isn't called in the `IntegrationFlow` below anyway. That confuses more, too.

What I only can say that `ActivitiInboundGateway` is **blocked** component (see `ActivitiInboundGateway.execute()`):

```
Message<?> reply = sendAndReceiveMessage(mb.build());
```

This is exactly blocking `request/reply` behavior. And we see its correct call with your `IntegrationFlow` definition.

Please, share more info to understand the case.

**UPDATE**

> I would like to make async process.
>
> ```
>  <serviceTask id="task-integration" name="task integration" activiti:delegateExpression="#{activitiDelegate}"/>
> ```

Looks like you can extends `IntegrationActivityBehavior`:

```
public class AsyncIntegrationActivityBehavior extends IntegrationActivityBehavior {
   
   private TaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

    @Override
    public void execute(final ActivityExecution execution) throws Exception {
        this.executor(new Runnable() {

                  public void void run() {
                     AsyncIntegrationActivityBehavior.super.execute(execution);
                       }
               });
    }

}
```

and use it for your `activitiDelegate` `@Bean`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. You are right. ActivitiInboundGateway is blocked. Is there any another way? serviceTask only sends request message and process immediately is stoped. Then some receiver starts up process again with response message.   I do not know if i can solve it within spring integation or only bpmn activiti. For example, Request message from serviceTask can be processed only in the night processing.

Comment: See an UPDATE to my answer.